# How to disable a button using React useState hook inside event handler

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-lamport-lfqwt?file=/src/App.js:0-678

Using a state hook

```
const [loading, _setLoading] = useState(false)
```

A button needs to be disabled  based on the the state above

```
 return (
        <div className="App">
          <button type="button"
             onClick={handleSubmit}
              disabled={loading}> Send </button>
        </div>
      );
```

The eventhandler is

```
 async function handleSubmit(event) {
        setLoading(true)
        console.log(loadingRef.current)

        await setTimeout( () => {} , 3000)
        
        setLoading(false)
        console.log(loadingRef.current)
  }
```

The button needs to be disabled while setTimeout waits for three seconds

React stores the default loading state in a closure when running the event handler later. So I use a useRef to access current value inside the handler ( not related with what needs to be achieved which is..) how to disable the button for three seconds based on the loading state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple issues here:

1. `setTimeout` does not return a Promise, so `await` isn't delaying execution of your second `setLoading` call.
2. You are passing `onclick` (all lowercase) instead of `onClick` to `<Button>`.

Resolving these (and clearing out your ref stuff as you said it wasn't related), you land at this working example ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-murdock-hgmgd?file=/src/App.js)):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    setLoading(true);
    console.log(loading);

    await new Promise((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
      }, 3000)
    );

    setLoading(false);
    console.log(loading);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit} disabled={loading}>
        Send
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```